# To find latest modified DB that it can be stored procedure,tables,functions,views,indexes modified in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any query to find the latest modified (sp,tables,functions,views,indexes..) Databases in sql server? i also need the latest modified date of each databases .

NB: This question wont be a duplicate as my question is to find the latest modified DB as it can be anything modified like sp, tables, functions,views, indexes .

Comment: query `modified_date` of `sys.objects`

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution:

```
Select * from Sys.objects 
Where type_desc != 'SYSTEM_TABLE' 
AND type_desc != 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
AND type_desc != 'DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT'
AND type_desc != 'INTERNAL_TABLE'
AND type_desc != 'SERVICE_QUEUE'
Order By modify_date DESC
```

***Modify Query according to your requirement.***